# My ports stay open for like 2 minutes then they close and I have to "ping" in a game

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port, minecraft

I'm running a Minecraft server, I **port forwarded** the **25565 port** and when I do the check on [this website](http://ping.eu/port-chk/)
it says port **closed**

However, when I go to multiplayer in Minecraft and **refresh the list** and re-check it says port **opened**

Then after *2-3 minutes* if I don't refresh the server list and check the site if says port **closed**

*Then I refresh ports opened after 2-3 minutes port closed have to refresh to say opened again*

The router I'm using: Technicolor TG784n v3

Also, I noticed that when I "ping" in Minecraft this is logged on my router:
[image: when I ping]

Then, as I said, after a while:
[image: after a while]

Can someone help me?

Comment: You'll want to provide some more information, such as the router you're forwarding on, the OS being forwarded to, the status of this port on the server's firewall, and maybe a screenshot of the port forwarding page on the router config (redacting potentially sensitive information such as your public IP). And while you're doing that, double check that the server is listening on the same port on the server using netstat or something.

Comment: Is this a UDP or TCP port?

Comment: @mattm I opened in both

Comment: @Matt is right. Also some more info from the router log might help.

Comment: And if all else fails and you confirm that your server is listening on that port, you can see the port listening internally on your data network NOT going through your ISP router to get to, you can always reach out to your ISP and see if there's something they block at their level with the port(s) you use.Confirm exactly how the port forward rules are configured too as in using IP addresses only and not device or machine names, correct?

Comment: Do you have Comcast? They could be forcing the connection closed with a [TCP reset attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack). Try restarting your router. Mine gets flaky after a while.

Comment: @Chloe well I don't have comcast and I shutdown the router everyday to save some money

Comment: How you setup port forwarding? Did you set any trigger port or protocol? If yes, delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set trigger protocol and port, leave it `any` and epmpty.

1. Login router setup page
2. Go to `Toolbox > Game and application sharing`
3. Go to *`Create a new game or application`* to define group of forwarded ports
4. Set `Name` to `Minecraft server` and select *`Manual Entry of Port Maps`*
5. Set only:

   `Protocol   Port Range       Translate To...`
   `Any        25565 to 25565   25565`
6. now assign forwarding to host in LAN (your server), go to *`Assign a game or application to a local network device`*
7. Set

   `Game or Application         Device`
   `Minecraft server            IP_of_your_server`

test, it should work.